# Scala Slick autoincrementing field

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

This is a similar question to other autoincrement questions, but instead of providing a list of columns to define autoInc, I need to provide a table reference somehow. I am using MySQL

```
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._
import play.Logger
import slick.session.Database.threadLocalSession

object PaypalCartItems extends Table[PaypalCartItem]("paypalCartItem") {
  def id          = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def itemName    = column[String]("item_name")
  def sku         = column[String]("item_number")
  def quantity    = column[String]("quantity")
  def txnId       = column[String]("txn_id")
  def url         = column[String]("url")

  def * = itemName ~ sku ~ quantity ~ txnId ~ url ~ id <> (PaypalCartItem, PaypalCartItem.unapply _)

  // I don't want to list out the columns, I need to reference the table
  def autoInc = itemName ~ sku ~ quantity ~ txnId ~ url returning id

  def insertItems(items: List[PaypalCartItem]): List[PaypalCartItem] = items map { item: PaypalCartItem =>
    val newId = PaypalCartItems.autoInc.insert(item)
    item.copy(id=newId)
  }
}
```

The above code does not compile, giving the following:

```
[error]   overloaded method value insert with alternatives:
[error]   [TT](query: scala.slick.lifted.Query[TT,(String, String, String, String, String)])(implicit session: scala.slick.session.Session)Seq[Int] <and>
[error]   (value: (String, String, String, String, String))(implicit session: scala.slick.session.Session)Int
[error]  cannot be applied to (PaypalCartItem)
[error]     val newId = PaypalCartItems.autoInc.insert(item)
```

Comment: Not sure what you meant with "I need to provide a table reference somehow".

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will help you, but i do it like that:

```
def autoInc2 = * returning id.? into {
      case (Music(_, title, artist, album, isrc, ownerId), id) => Music(id, title, artist, album, isrc, ownerId)
    }
```

Where the first argument for Music is the id, Option[Int] in this case. And it's used as `val musicWithId = Musics.autoInc2.insert(someMusicObjectWithId)`

Comment: This approach works, but it is fragile and verbose. Each property of the case class must be enumerated twice. Better if the case class's copy constructor could be used instead, with a named parameter, or perhaps convert the case class properties to a tuple using unapply(music).get and then back again with a different value for id. Seems like a lot of fussing about, though